# convert system string to char to be passed to _mkdir function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am getting a text value from text box and need to pass this to a _mkdir function which takes char*.

So I have:

```
 _mkdir(this->txt_path->Text);
```

How do I convert this, I am using VS 2008 C++ and have .Net env.

I have looked at other online material which hasn't helped :(

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: -1:  This is the second time you have not posted relevant declarations & other important information.  If this is C++/CLI, it should be tagged as such, rather than as [C++]

Comment: If Text is `std::string` then `Text.c_str()` returns a `const char *`

Comment: You are failing to provide the type of `txt_path->Text`, which is the single most important thing to know for a conversion (that is, after the type to which you want to convert...)

Answer (score 1):

Well, like most C API's this one is probably not const correct.  You could try to pass in Text.c_str() and see what happens.

If it really does need to modify the string though then first of all, find another function to use, this is a very unsafe one.  Second of all, you can use it by doing this:

```
std::vector<char> buf(Text.begin(), Text.end());
buf.push_back(0);
_mkdir(&buf[0]);
```

Comment: This assumes that `Text` is a `std::string`.  Judging from this poster's history, that might not be the case.